# while create a new project using ng in angular i am getting following errors

Tags: angular

```
C:\Users\vipul>ng new sample-project
? Would you like to add Angular routing? Yes
? Which stylesheet format would you like to use? CSS
- Installing packages (npm)...npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: sample-project@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: jasmine-core@3.7.1
npm ERR! node_modules/jasmine-core
npm ERR!   dev jasmine-core@"~3.7.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer jasmine-core@">=3.8" from karma-jasmine-html-reporter@1.7.0
npm ERR! node_modules/karma-jasmine-html-reporter
npm ERR!   dev karma-jasmine-html-reporter@"^1.5.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\vipul\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\vipul\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-07-12T20_18_58_836Z-debug.log
× Package install failed, see above.
The Schematic workflow failed. See above.
? Would you like to add Angular routing? Yes
? Which stylesheet format would you like to use? CSS
- Installing packages (npm)...npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: sample-project@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: jasmine-core@3.7.1
npm ERR! node_modules/jasmine-core
npm ERR!   dev jasmine-core@"~3.7.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer jasmine-core@">=3.8" from karma-jasmine-html-reporter@1.7.0
npm ERR! node_modules/karma-jasmine-html-reporter
npm ERR!   dev karma-jasmine-html-reporter@"^1.5.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\vipul\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\vipul\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-07-12T20_18_58_836Z-debug.log
× Package install failed, see above.
The Schematic workflow failed. See above.
```

Comment: This question has been asked, but I have never seen someone explain how to fix your global files. This is a pain when you are just learning Angular and a new project will not just generate as intended. So I provided an answer (for Windows systems). If you're on a mac or Linux, I'm sorry I don't know the global directory by heart. The idea is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Jasmine had an update again.

To fix your global files, in:

C:\Users\<USER_NAME>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@schematics\angular\workspace\files

Edit 'package.json.template':

```
"@types/jasmine": "~3.8.0",<% } %>
...
"jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
...
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.7.0",<% } %>
```

For just the project you are working on:

Do the same for its 'package.json' & run npm install.

Answer (score 0):

1. `npm uninstall -g @angular/cli`
2. `npm cache vertify`
3. `npm cache clear -- force`
4. `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`